# DefaultMessageListenerContainer Number of sessions per connection

Tags: spring-jms

I'm getting a warning

```
[org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] (Camel (camelContext) thread #530 - JmsConsumer[Q.TEST1]) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Q.TEST1' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJCA1018: Une seule session par connexion est autorisée.
```

The default value in the DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer is set to 2.

Is it required to set it to 1 to avoid this Warning?
Or it's better to change MQ setting to accept multiple sessions?
Why It's a Warning, I expecting an error since the Listener will not consume the messgae.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running in a JEE environment.  A JCA managed connection will only be allowed a single session per connection as per the JCA specification.

Using a JCA/JEE managed connection factory is very useful.  For example, transaction management is provided.  If, however, you do not need the functionality provided by the JEE container, you are free to instantiate your own connection factory, something like:

```
<bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" id="mqConnectionFactory">
    <property name="connectionNameList" value="mqhost(1414)"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="MY.QMGR"/>
    <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"/>
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
    <property name="clientReconnectOptions" value="67108864"/>
</bean>
```

This non-JCA administered connection factory will be able to have more than one sesssion per connection.

Comment: Yes I'm in a JEE environment and I would like to keep the connection factory managed by the application server (there are other parmeteres that should be set in the application server). I'm refencing it by <jee:jndi-lookup id="qf1" jndi-name="java:/qf1"/>. Maybe a bean to override the default value of cached-sessions to 1?

Comment: Your problem is that the JCA spec limits you to one session per connection.  I know that there is a property on the IBM MQ JCA that can disable this check.  I can't seem to find it right now.  I think that the best thing to do would be to run multiple copies of your listener, if you want to be JCA managed.